# Little Help for Wordpress Adding Php

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed "Allow PHP in Post and Pages" plugin on my wordpress site.

I try to create page for sharing their snapchat instagram account on that page but some code are not shown. I dont know much thing about php. could you help me?

http://tefo.tv/snap-2/

This code is published on my page;

```
[php]
include("share/connect.php");
[/php]


<div style="float:left">
<form action="http://tefo.tv/share/kaydet.php" method="post">
App: <select name="app">
<option value="Snapchat">Snapchat</option>
<option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
<option value="Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
</select>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Sex: <select name="sex">
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>

<script> 
    $(function() { 
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); 
    }); 
    </script> 

Birthday: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"><br>
Country: <select name="country">
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Rusia">Rusia</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select><br>




<input type="submit" VALUE="Gönder">
</form>
</div>
<!-- Main Part -->

        <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:auto; " border="1">
            <tr style="background:#D5D4D2; color:#777777;" border="1">
            <th>Application</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Like</th>
            <th>Unlike</th>
        </table>

        [php]

        $list = mysql_query("select * from wp_snap") or die(bok);
                while($list1 = mysql_fetch_array($list))
                {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td align="center">'.$list1['app'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['username'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['sex'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['age'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['country'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['date'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['like'].'<a href="#"><img src="share/like.png" width="10" height="10" alt="Örnek Resim"></a></td></br>';
                echo '<td>'.$list1['unlike'].'<a href="#"><img src="share/dis.png" width="10" height="10" alt="Örnek Resim"></a></td></br>';
                echo '</tr>';             
                }





        [/php]



</table>
```

This is kaydet.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

//Form post metoduyla gönderilen bilgileri alıp değişkenlere atayalım.
$app = $_POST['app'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$datepicker = $_POST['datepicker'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
//Veritabanında bulunan 'defter' isimli tablonun 'defter_isim' ve 'defter_soyisim' alanlarına kayıt edelim.
$kaydet = mysql_query("insert into users (app, username, sex, age, country) values ('$app', '$username', '$sex', '$datepicker', '$country')") or die("Hata: kayıt işlemi gerçekleşemedi.");

header("refresh:0;url=index.php");
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your   [/php] tag is after HTML code. It should be right after the include like so:

```
[php]      
include("add/connect.php");
[/php]
```

The rest of your code is not php so it is breaking your form.

Comment: thank you it works but entries not shown under the other. how can i fix